# Замыкание значения

Tags: javascript

Возможно ли в JavaScript функции замкнуть значение, а не переменную? Т.е. если смотреть на пример предполагается, что `l` будет изменяться, а необходимо чтобы выводилось значение `l` на момент создания замыкания.

```
function() {
    var l = 1;

    return function() {
        console.log(l);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
function() {
  var l = 1;
  return (function(l) {
    return function() {
      console.log(l);
    };
  })(l);
}
```